# How to model the inside corner of where two curved walls meet?

Tags: geometry

I'm pretty new to 3D modeling and Blender and I'm trying to make a modular tileset which includes walls. I'm stumped at exactly how to shape the inside corner where two of my curved walls meet. The current way I've done it obviously causes artifacts and doesn't look quite right. I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around the geometry in this area so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Even if I have to redo the whole thing.

[image: The corner in question][image: zoomed out view]

Comment: If everything is modeled with clean topology, no duplicate vertices, no overlaps, flipped faces etc., why should it cause artifacts? I don't really see artifacts, it's flat shading in solid view, the shading does not necessarily look perfect in this mode. And apart from that, what do you want it to look like? Outside the red area you have sharp corners, so why should the red area not be sharp as well? What do you want there?